# Getting Below Kubernites Pod restart Problem with pymongo lib

Tags: pymongo, python-3.8

I am running python application on aiohttp, I making multi db connection in mongo using pymongo lib., running in kubernites, pods is restaring again and again. I am using umongo==2.3.0

To troubleshoot the issue of pods restarting repeatedly in a Kubernetes environment while running a Python application with aiohttp, multiple MongoDB connections using pymongo, and umongo version 2.3.0

It sounds like you're encountering issues with your Python application running on aiohttp, specifically related to multiple database connections to MongoDB using pymongo in a Kubernetes environment

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30bf15ab38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30bf39eb38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c137bb38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c51d3b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c5a0fb38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c5caab38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c5e3db38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 139 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c5f40b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 139 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c6043b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 139 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c6146b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 139 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c6249b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/socket_checker.py", line 60 in select
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 275 in wait_for_read
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 320 in _receive_data_on_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 225 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 793 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 660 in _next_reply
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 269 in _check_with_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 249 in _check_once
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 214 in _check_server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 173 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 53 in target
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 124 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c634cb38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/socket_checker.py", line 60 in select
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 275 in wait_for_read
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 320 in _receive_data_on_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 225 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 793 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 660 in _next_reply
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 269 in _check_with_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 249 in _check_once
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 214 in _check_server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 173 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 53 in target
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 124 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c6453b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/socket_checker.py", line 60 in select
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 275 in wait_for_read
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 320 in _receive_data_on_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 225 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 793 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 660 in _next_reply
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 269 in _check_with_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 249 in _check_once
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 214 in _check_server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 173 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 53 in target
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 124 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c6c00b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 139 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c6d03b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 139 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c6e06b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 139 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c6f09b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 139 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c700cb38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/socket_checker.py", line 60 in select
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 275 in wait_for_read
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 320 in _receive_data_on_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 225 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 793 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 660 in _next_reply
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 269 in _check_with_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 249 in _check_once
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 214 in _check_server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 173 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 53 in target
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 124 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c710fb38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/socket_checker.py", line 60 in select
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 275 in wait_for_read
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 320 in _receive_data_on_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 225 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 793 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 660 in _next_reply
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 269 in _check_with_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 249 in _check_once
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 214 in _check_server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 173 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 53 in target
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 124 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c7212b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/socket_checker.py", line 60 in select
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 275 in wait_for_read
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 320 in _receive_data_on_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 225 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 793 in receive_message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 660 in _next_reply
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 269 in _check_with_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 249 in _check_once
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 214 in _check_server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 173 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 53 in target
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 124 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f30c7315b38 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap
```

I have tried with change the verson of pymongo and other supporting libs.
but not got any resolution.